# "async" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

Tags: html, adsense, w3c-validation

Running my site through the W3C validator (and in other validators), I'm getting the following errors with my Google Ads:

> - `async` is not a member of a group specified for any attribute
> - there is no attribute `data-ad-client`
> - there is no attribute `data-ad-slot`

Is there anyway to correct these? I'd love to see the site pass 100%.

Answer (score 6):

The `async` attribute (for the `script` element) and the `data-*` attributes were introduced with HTML5.

You likely get the errors because you are using an earlier HTML version (like HTML 4.01).

To fix this, you have to use HTML5 or a later version. The latest version can always be found at https://www.w3.org/TR/html/.

For many documents it’s sufficient to switch to the new DOCTYPE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```